# Proving that there exist a semidirect group

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

Problem:

Let $G$ be the set of 3-by-3 matrices such that they have exactly one nonzero entry in each row, and exactly one nonzero entry in each column, and the nonzero entries are only $\pm1$. Prove that $G \cong S_3 \rtimes H$ where $H$ is the group of 3-by-3 matrices that are diagonal with $\pm 1$ along the diagonal, and $S_3$ is the group of bijections of $\{1,2,3\}$

I can see that the semidirect product shuffles the columns of a matrix in $H$ to all the possible combinations, but I can't prove the necessary properties. They are,

$$H \triangleleft G, S_3 \leq G$$
$$H \cap S_3=\{e\}$$
$$H S_3 = G$$

Comment: First, do you see how $S_3$ is a subgroup in $G$?

Comment: Do I have to construct an isomorphism from $S_3$ to elements of $G$?

Comment: Just see which matrices in $G$ correspond to permutations (I have a feeling the question assumes that this should look familiar to you).

Comment: Yes, but I can't see which ones are those

Comment: Consider those where all entries are either $0$ or $1$.